# Error: Filter chain halted as :authenticate! rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, session, authentication, token

I have an application which has **base_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate!

  private

  def authenticate!
    session_token = request.env["HTTP_SESSIONTOKEN"]
    @current_user = User.find_by(session_token: session_token) unless session_token.blank?
    unless @current_user
      return render_json(message: "ERROR: Invalid Session")
    end
  end

  def render_json(data, status = :ok)
    render json: data, status: status
  end
end
```

when I called sign_in action which is in **session_controller.rb** which inherits base controller,it gives "Invalid Session".
I tried using postman and when I tried debugging using "binding.pry" in authenticate! method then it gives session_token as nil,why it is giving nil as i given latest session token of user.
My application worked well till yesterday.

Comment: Could you post your `session_controller.rb` code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sessiontoken` instead of `session_token` in header name worked for me.